# POST Method doesn't work MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I try Create a new article in my table art, but the POST Method doesn't work, i don't now why, , Edit Article working perfectly, i read many post form that topic and nothing, i hope anyone can help me

**Model**

```
public class Art
{        
    [Key]
    public int idArt { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Codigo Artículo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Codigo Artículo Requerido")]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string co_art { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo Articulo")]
    [ForeignKey("TypeArticles")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tipo Artículo Requerido")]
    public int IDType { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeArticles TypeArticles { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Descripción")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descripción Artículo Requerido")]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string des_art { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Modelo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Modelo Artículo Requerido")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string modelo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Referencia")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Referencia Artículo Requerido")]
    public string referencia { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Linea Artículo")]
    [ForeignKey("Linea")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Linea Artículo Requerido")]
    public int IdLinea { get; set; }
    public virtual Linea Linea { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Categoria Artículo")]
    [ForeignKey("Categoria")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Categoria Artículo Requerido")]
    public int idCat { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }        

    [DisplayName("Precio Venta")]
    [Range(0.01, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Precio debe estar entre 0.01 y 999999999")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1024)]
    [DisplayName("Info. Adicional")]
    public string Adicional { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller POST Method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(Art artmodels)
    {
        ViewBag.idLinea = new SelectList(db.Linea.OrderBy(c => c.des_lin), "IdLinea", "des_lin");
        ViewBag.IdCat = new SelectList(db.Categorias.OrderBy(c => c.des_cat), "IdCat", "des_cat");
        ViewBag.IDType = new SelectList(db.TypeArticles.OrderBy(c => c.TypeDesc), "IDType", "TypeDesc");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var art_exists = (from inv in db.Art where inv.co_art == artmodels.co_art.Trim() select inv).FirstOrDefault();
            if (art_exists != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("co_art", "Codigo de Articulo ya Existe");
                return View(artmodels);
            }

            db.Art.Add(artmodels);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ///
            //int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
            //var articulos = db.Art;

            //IPagedList<Art> art_paged = null;
            //art_paged = articulos.OrderBy(i => i.co_art).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, (pagesize.HasValue) ? pagesize.Value : defaultPageSize);

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Articulos", new {id = artmodels.idArt });                
        }       

        this.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return View(artmodels);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model mvcAmerica.Models.Art
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Creacion";
}

<h1><small>Creación Articulos</small></h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articulos", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <text>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("CreateOrEditArticulos", Model);}
    </text>
}
```

**RenderPartial**

```
@model mvcAmerica.Models.Art


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idArt)

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.co_art)

            <div class="input">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.co_art)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.co_art)
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.des_art)

        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.des_art)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.des_art)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDType, "Tipo Articulo")

        <div class="input chosen-select">
            @Html.DropDownList("IDType", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDType)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.modelo)

        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.modelo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.modelo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.referencia)

        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.referencia)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.referencia)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdLinea)

        <div class="input chosen-select">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdLinea", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdLinea)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCat)

        <div class="input chosen-select">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdCat", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCat)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adicional)

        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adicional)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adicional)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Guardar" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Listado", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Thanks for the help that bring me in this problem...

Comment: **what** does not work? Have you tried to set some brakepoints in the `Create` function?

Comment: Yes, I Try, in method GET and POST, the method GET pass perfectly, but the Method POST don't, is who don't calling that the submit button....

Comment: you are using in the view _and_ the partial `Html.BeginForm()` ? I dont know exactly, but i think this is not correct?

Comment: Work perfectly in my other Views in the project... Proposal and Purchase

Comment: you have two nested forms that is the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EhsanSajjad but i have two views that work with two nested forms without problem... one is the proposal form and the other is purchase both with details. Now, this one, why don't work?

Comment: two separate form can work but nested forms can't

Comment: if you see your code in Form you are rendering partial view and in that partial view there is another form

Comment: Yes, i see that, in my others view working perfectly... but in this don't, i will try other path to see, thanks @EhsanSajjad

Comment: but it is wrong the way you doing..

Comment: use Form in partial view or main view

Comment: I see the problem, in the other views, i send a preparate model with certains values, in this, don't, mi key field is not prepared and the field @html.HidderFor() only used for information edit or deleted, i change and work... but i follow your advice from the two nested form, thank you @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested forms in your code which is causing this issue. The Submit button is in the inner  but it dies not have any Controller and Anction methods to call, So it's not post the data to any method.

So you need to change this code something like this:

**View**

```
@model mvcAmerica.Models.Art
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Creacion";
}

<h1><small>Creación Articulos</small></h1>

//the commented line should go to the partial view
//@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articulos", FormMethod.Post))
//{
//    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <text>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("CreateOrEditArticulos", Model);}
    </text>
```

**RenderPartial**

```
@model mvcAmerica.Models.Art

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articulos", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   // rest of the code is as it is
}
```